# Mouse hovering(similar to hint) delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Is there any event that determines, if the mouse is hovering above an edit box? Basically, I want to show a hint/help for the user, but I want to display an image and simple instructions. What would be the best way to proceed?

Thanks for any help

Comment: [`TApplication.OnHint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnHint)

Comment: Use a custom hint class? You're not limited to standard hints only, you can make popup hints that show anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`OnMouseEnter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnMouseEnter) and [`OnMouseLeave`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnMouseLeave) events. In the event handlers, you can set the visibility of a `Label` or simliar control with the hint text. In the example, I took an empty VCL form and inserted a [`TEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit) and a [`TLabel`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TLabel). I implemented the `OnMouseMEnter` and the `OnMouseLeave` events:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Edit1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edit1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Edit1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Label1.Visible:=True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Label1.Visible:=False;
end;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When the label becomes not visible, the OnEnter event doesn't fire...

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be to use the `OnMouseEnter` and `OnMouseLeave` events.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample found on [Embarcadero](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_OnHint.html):

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    procedure DisplayHint(Sender: TObject);
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
implementation
{$R *.dfm}

{ Here is the implementation of the OnHint event handler }
{ It displays the application’s current hint in the status bar }
procedure TForm1.DisplayHint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StatusBar1.SimpleText := GetLongHint(Application.Hint);
end;
{ Here is the form’s OnCreate event handler. }
{ It assign’s the application’s OnHint event handler at runtime }
{ because the Application is not available in the Object Inspector }
{ at design time }
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnHint := DisplayHint;
end;
```

You can use special tag on HINT property of `TLabel`, then manage the output as you need.

Comment: Better to use `TApplicationEvents` than to assign directly to `TApplication.OnHint`.

Comment: I use this a lot to display the hints in the status bar, to "force" the user to read them.